# Multiple event listeners with same function storing separate local variables?

Tags: javascript, closures, event-listener, local-variables

I'm fairly new to closures in javascript (certainly when applying them to event handlers!), and trying to grasp the underlying principles leading to the behavior of this code:

```js
function showClick() {
  var clicks = 0
  return function(e) {
    clicks++
    console.log("click "+clicks+" at "+[e.clientX,e.clientY])
    return clicks
  }
}

document.getElementById("b1").onclick=showClick() 
document.getElementById("b2").onclick=showClick()
```

```html
<button id="b1">Record my Clicks</button> <!--only stores click history of b1, disregarding b2-->

<button id="b2">Record MY Clicks</button> <!--only stores click history of b2, disregarding b1-->
```

I can see that the value for "clicks" is being updated and stored (presumably in the event handler function return?) each time I trigger the event, but is only doing so for the respective button being clicked. How are these values being stored, and why aren't they being shared between the two event handlers? Would I need to assign a variable outside the scope of both if I want the value of "clicks" to be shared between both buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to think in 'scopes'. When you call `showClick()` there is a scope. Inside this scope it creates a variable, called 'clicks'. This variable is valid within this function and all subfunctions / closures.

The function returns a new function, a so called closure. This closure keeps access to the scope of the encapsulated function. Everytime when you call `showClick()` a new scope is generated and within this scope the variable `clicks`. Furthermore there is the closure created and returned. The scopes, the variables within this scopes and the closures are not the same. There different everytime you call showClicks.

That's the reason why they count seperately for both links.

If you want to count both clicks together... there are multiple solutions.

- First you could remove the closure. you dont't need it.
- Save the closure as the context of the showClick function and use it everytime if showClick is called
- save the clicks in global scope (not recommended)

**EDIT:** Like asked in the comments here two approaches to save the closure and reuse it:

1) The "Singleton-Approach I" (save the closure itself)

```
function showClick() {
    if(showClick.closure) return showClick.closure;
    var clicks = 0;
    return showClick.closure = function(evt) {
        clicks++;
        console.log(clicks+' at '+evt.clientX+' / '+evt.clientY);
    }
}
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = showClick();
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].onclick = showClick();
```

2) The "Singleton-Approach II" (save the clickcount)

```
function showClick() {
    showClick.clicks = showClick.clicks || 0;
    return function(evt) {
        showClick.clicks++;
        console.log(showClick.clicks+' at '+evt.clientX+' / '+evt.clientY);
    }
}
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = showClick();
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].onclick = showClick();
```

3) The "Context-Approach" (save the closure as the context of the factory function)

```
var showClick = (function showClick() {
    return this;
}).bind((function() {
    var clicks = 0;
    return function(evt) {
        clicks++;
        console.log(clicks+' at '+evt.clientX+' / '+evt.clientY);
    };
})());
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = showClick();
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].onclick = showClick();
```

Comment: @JoshuaK The second bullet point sounds like the approach I'm looking to take, but can you clarify that statement a bit more? I'm interpreting it as a more generalized version of the description ishegg gave (i.e., assign a function value to a variable which is subsequently used for both event listeners)

Comment: @JonathanStraus I added some examples. I hope it helps. If you have any further questions feel free to ask. (Don't forget to select an answer if your question is fully answered :))

Answer (score 2):

You are creating multiple instances of the function. Each one of those instances has their own `clicks` variable, which is why they're increasing on their own. You have several options, amongst them:

**Keep a reference to the function:**

```
function showClick() {
    var clicks = 0;
    return function(e) {
        clicks++
        console.log("click "+clicks+" at "+[e.clientX,e.clientY])
        return clicks
    }
}
var clickEvent = showClick(); // we instance the function only once
document.getElementById("b1").onclick=clickEvent; // and use it here
document.getElementById("b2").onclick=clickEvent; // and here
```

**Keep the variable in the global scope**

```
function showClick() {
    this.clicks = 0; // this === window here
    return function(e) {
        clicks++
        console.log("click "+clicks+" at "+[e.clientX,e.clientY])
        return clicks
    }
}
document.getElementById("b1").onclick=showClick();
document.getElementById("b2").onclick=showClick();
```

Comment: `this.clicks = 0; // this === window here` Don't put the variable in the global scope, there is no need for that. Just place it in a scope above the factory function.

Comment: Linking the 'function values' with a common variable makes perfect sense to me! Had no idea you could use the 'event' keyword in that way without other potentially undesirable side effects though. I assume it would be equally effective if I put the function expression "var showClick = function (){...}" in place of my original function declaration?

Comment: @JoshuaK of course, it was only for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @JonathanStraus I just realized it about the `event` variable name! I'll change it... And no, it wouldn't work either: you'd still be instantiating the function twice if you called it that.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `showClick()` twice, and assigning the result of each call to its respective event listener. Here's an easy way to look at it:

```js
function showClick() {
  var clicks = 0
  return function(e) {
    clicks++
    console.log("click "+clicks+" at "+[e.clientX,e.clientY])
    return clicks
  }
}

var clickHandler1 = showClick();
document.getElementById("b1").onclick=clickHandler1;
var clickHandler2 = showClick();
document.getElementById("b2").onclick=clickHandler2;
```

Here's another way of looking at it:

```js
document.getElementById("b1").onclick=(function() {
  var clicks = 0
  return function(e) {
    clicks++
    console.log("click "+clicks+" at "+[e.clientX,e.clientY])
    return clicks
  }
})();
document.getElementById("b2").onclick=(function() {
  var clicks = 0
  return function(e) {
    clicks++
    console.log("click "+clicks+" at "+[e.clientX,e.clientY])
    return clicks
  }
})();
```

These functions have the same function definition, but they do not share instance variables.

If you want to share the variable between the two, just forget about the factory function entirely (note that this does not call the function, it assigns the function to the event listener):

```js
var clicks = 0
function showClick(e) {
  clicks++
  console.log("click "+clicks+" at "+[e.clientX,e.clientY])
  return clicks
}

document.getElementById("b1").onclick=showClick;
document.getElementById("b2").onclick=showClick;
```

Comment: "This does not call the function, it assigns the function to the event listener."  That may have been my key misunderstanding about how the inner function in the event handler works. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Example 2: you can save the clickcount as the context instead of using a anonymous function. It's a way shorter. || Example 3: `clicks` in global scope is not a good idea. Here is the right place for a wrapping anonymous function  to keep the scope clean. And again: You can save the clickcount as the context to avoid this 'problem'.

Comment: In response to my answer: _just forget about the factory function entirely_ read about the correct naming (links are in my response to your comment). The outher function is the factory function and the inner function is the closure. Another source: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures, You can find three more in my other response :)

Comment: @JoshuaK Re: "global scope" ultimately, very little should ever be run in the global scope. I would assume that all of this would be wrapped in a function of some sort. Re: closure naming, sorry I got that switched around in my head for some reason. You are correct. I have deleted my comment on your answer but cannot change my vote due to voting lock until your post is edited in some way.

Comment: @TinyGiant no problem :) Thank you. it happens to the best of us.